# Primary key composed of two foreign keys? Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a question regarding a table creation. I want to combine the attributes of "Ono" and "Pno" into a primary key for a new table. These are both foreign keys, each from different tables. Do I just use a CONSTRAINT Ono_Pno_PK PRIMARY KEY (Ono,Pno)?

what I have used so far:

```
CREATE TABLE ODetails
(
    Ono Number Not Null,
    Pno Number Not Null,
    Qty Number(3) Not Null,
    Creation_Date Date Not Null,
    Created_By VARCHAR(10) Not Null,
    Last_Update_Date Date Not Null,
    Last_Updated_By VARCHAR2(10) Not Null,
    CONSTRAINT Ono_FK FOREIGN KEY (Ono) REFERENCES Orders (Ono),
    CONSTRAINT Pno_FK FOREIGN KEY (Pno) REFERENCES Parts (Pno)
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just add this line after the constraints,

```
CONSTRAINT tb_PK PRIMARY KEY (Ono, Pno)
```

Comment: Good Answer.  It's likely to help anybody who wants to use compound primary keys.  Visitors should see the following: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key